# Visual Studio Code Map - hanging on "Indexing the code: Connecting to code index." step

Tags: visual-studio-2022, code-map

I am trying to generate code map in Visual Studio Enterprise for solution with > 100 projects (C++, C# and C++/CLI). When I click on project in solution explorer and choose option "Show on Code Map", new window appears with namespace and dll name. However it is not possible to expand dll to see code map inside it. On the top of the window there is an information "Indexing the code: Connecting to code index".
Finally after about 40 minutes I am getting the following exception:
[image]
This is an information in Graph Output:
[image]
I tried also using code map for solution with one small project and it is working.
I reinstalled code map feature (Visual Studio Installer) but it didn't solve the issue.
My colleague was unable to use code map for the same solution with multiple projects as well.

Do you have any ideas how to make code map working for solution with multiple projects?